# Проверить существование класса по имени в строковой переменной

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

cl = "className";

Как проверить существование класса по имени в строковой переменной cl?
А затем, если он существует, создать объект этого класса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как таковых **классов** в EMAScript нет. Есть функции-конструкторы.

Проверить, является ли строка названием конструктора можно так

```js
function constr() {return {a: true}};

let name = "constr";

let exists = typeof window[name] === "function";
console.log(exists)

if (exists) {
    var c = new window[name]();
}

console.log(c);
```

В этом случае мы проверяем, является ли свойство `name`, содержащее название класса, функцией. Если является, значит такая функция есть, а любая функция может быть вызвана как конструктор.

Можно и при помощи `eval` (но помним об `eval is evil`). Полезно для синтаксиса ES6, где есть ключевое слово `class`, которое не попадает в `window` в виде функции, хотя ей же и является.

```js
class K {
    constructor() {
        return {a: 1};
    }
}

let name = "K";

let exists = eval("typeof " + name + " === 'function';");
console.log(exists);
```

Comment: `class`-ы отлично попадают в window, если их объявлять в глобальном контексте.

Comment: @AlexeyTen ну я на скорую руку набросал - не заработало. Может упустил что-то. Пишите свой ответ, никто ж не запрещает ;) В любом случае оба ответа работают.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то вот так:

```
function Rabbit() {}

// создаём объект
var rabbit = new Rabbit();

// проверяем -- этот объект создан Rabbit?
if( rabbit instanceof Rabbit ){ // если возвращает true - создаем новый объект этого класса
     var rabbit_2 = new Rabbit();
}
```